# Raspbian (debian) file permissions do not persist after setting with chmod

Tags: linux, raspbian, debian-based

I'm new to linux as I just purchased a raspberrypi.
When I use chmod to change the permissions of a .py file so that I can execute it, and add -v at the end:   "chmod a+x test.py -v "           the changed permissions are displayed as changed  " rwxr-xr-x "
then when I enter " ls -l ", the permissions are as they were before I used chmod.
" rw-r--r-- "
What's going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The files that I was trying to give "execute" privilege to were on a usb memory stick. When I moved them to the home directory I was able to change them.
So, perhaps their location caused my problem.
Peter